# how to add the path for of specific header file in QNX momentics IDE?

Tags: c, rtos, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I created a QNX c project and added some libraries and .c file in that. I want to add the path for the .h file in QNX momentics ide. There is no option for it. I created a QNX c project. Could someone help me in this ??

Comment: Are you building on QNX, Windows, or Linux? Are you trying to include a QNX header, or your own header?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check page 61 at the user guide [QNX Momentics -- IDE User's Guide](http://fusion.qnx.com/4/10404/IDE_userguide.pdf?tid=146432_lS_0204070035&ending=IDE_userguide.pdf)

Comment: I created a new QNX c project but there is no path and symbol option. could you please help me ??